# Changing elemets style with a slider(input range)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have variable/object that has key-value pair `element-id : opacity` called container (line 60 in examples).

For loop iterates for each `id` in that collection and creates slider on top of that element. That slider has a start value the same one as `opacity`.

The slider listens and should change the `opacity`, and it does. But it only changes the css on the last element that gets created.

The "working" code can be found on [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/vb9e6y41/) Try both of sliders to see.

My question is, why slider on the first element stopped listening on events, and the last one that got created still listens and changes css appropriately? Also, if there is only one item in `container` object, the code [works as it should for every element.](https://jsfiddle.net/7gz63dkz/1/)

Also, what tweaks and changes in logic do I need to make to get this working? Any inputs/insides are welcome. Thanks in advance!

```js
function createSlider(elem, html) {
    /**
        <input id="range_test" type="range">
        Hello, world!
    **/
    // create message element
    let message = document.createElement('div');
    /**
        <div>
    **/
    // better to use a css class for the style here
    message.style.cssText = "position:absolute; color: red";
    /**
        position: fixed; color: red;
    **/
    // assign coordinates, don't forget "px"!
    let coords = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    /**
        DOMRect { x: 551.5, y: 73.83332824707031, width: 160, height: 17.333343505859375, top: 73.83332824707031, right: 711.5, bottom: 91.16667175292969, left: 551.5 }
    **/
    message.style.left = coords.left + "px";
    message.style.top = coords.top + "px";
    message.style.zIndex = '1992';
    /**
        551.5px
        73.8333px
        1992
    **/

    message.appendChild(html);


    return message;
    /**
        <div style="position: fixed; color: red; left: 551.5px; top: 73.8333px; z-index: 1992;">
    **/
}
// id = new_price

// Generates slider for each id in object
function generateSlider(value_of_slider) {
    var new_slider = document.createElement("INPUT");
    new_slider.setAttribute("type", "range");
    new_slider.value = value_of_slider * 100;

    return new_slider;
}

// Changes the style of id
function changeStyle(id, value) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(id);

    elements.forEach((element) => {
        element.style.opacity = value;
    });

    console.log("The value of "+id+" is "+value);
}

var container = {
    "#new_price": "0.4",
};
for (id in container) {
    changeStyle(id, container[id]);
    var first_element = document.querySelector(id);
    var generate_slider = generateSlider(container[id]);

    let slider = createSlider(first_element, generate_slider);
    document.body.append(slider);

    generate_slider.addEventListener('input', () => {
        container[id] = (generate_slider.value / 100).toString();
        changeStyle(id, container[id]);
    });

};
```

```css
/*--------------------
Mixins
---------------------*/
/*--------------------
Body
---------------------*/
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(75deg, #d33f34 50%, #a61322 50.1%);
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, #d33f34 50%, #a61322 50.1%);
}

/*--------------------
Shop Card
---------------------*/
.shop-card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 350px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
.shop-card figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none !important;
}
.shop-card figure img {
  margin: -95px 0 -60px;
  width: 110%;
}
.shop-card .title {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #23211f;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.shop-card .desc {
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: .8;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.shop-card .cta {
  padding: 20px 20px 5px;
}
.shop-card .cta::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.shop-card .price {
  float: left;
  color: #FF3100;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-top: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.shop-card .btn {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FF3100;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  line-height: .95;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #FF3100;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shop-card .btn .bg {
  width: 101%;
  height: 101%;
  display: block !important;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #a61322, #d33f34);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #a61322, #d33f34);
}
.shop-card .btn:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  border: 1px solid transparent !important;
}
.shop-card .btn:hover .bg {
  opacity: 1;
}

/*--------------------
Slick Dots
---------------------*/
.slick-dots {
  bottom: -30px;
}
.slick-dots a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
.slick-dots span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.slick-dots circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 39 39;
  stroke-dashoffset: 39;
  -webkit-transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s;
}
.slick-dots .slick-active circle {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

/*--------------------
Background
--------------------*/
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(75deg, #d33f34 50%, #a61322 50.1%);
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, #d33f34 50%, #a61322 50.1%);
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
    <div id="the_card" class="shop-card">
        <div class="title"> calça clorinda bordada black </div>
        <div class="desc">
            Womans cloath
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
            <figure data-color="#E24938, #A30F22 ">
                <img src=" http://images.animaleabrand.com.br/commerce/animale/medias/produtos/Medium_04.23.0238_0005_EF_R.jpg " />
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div id="new_price" class="cta">
            <div class="price"> 6x de R$ 126,33</div><br>
            <div class="price"> 6x de R$ 126,33</div>
        </div>
        <div id="new_price" class="cta">
            <div class="price"> 6x de R$ 126,33</div><br>
            <div class="price"> 6x de R$ 126,33</div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="bg"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Please put your code in your post on this site before your question gets closed.

Comment: `#id`s **MUST BE UNIQUE** otherwise you'll only end up doing everything on the first one because the browser will no longer look for any other elements of that id because logically there should be only one.

Comment: Even if there is only one div per ID, the problem is the same. Did you mean the sliders ID?

Comment: `#new_price` change to `#new_price1` and `#new_price2` and instead of `document.querySelectorAll(id);` change the `id` to `'.cta'` Instead of `forEach()` use `.map()` so you can iterate by `id` ex. `array.map(element, index) { var ID = element.id;...` `map() can return an array of ids or create an object on each iteration. The object can have several unique keys/values per ID returned on an array.

Comment: @zer00ne forEach has element, index too

Comment: *"But it only changes the css on the last element that gets created."* `changeStyle()` only ever gets one value on id parameter so yeah, even if you were to correctly gather the slides in an array of two `.cta`s  the for...in loop only processes one iteration because `container[id]` is only one entry so it's length = 1;

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Can you provide some concrete code? @zer00ne

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for everyone that is interested in how I managed to pull it out, here is the code.

```js
'use strict';

// Generates slider for each id in object
function generateSlider(value_of_slider) {
    var new_slider = document.createElement("INPUT");
    new_slider.setAttribute("type", "range");
    new_slider.value = value_of_slider * 100;

    return new_slider;
}

var x = document.querySelectorAll('.ctg');

var y = Array.map(x, (element, i)=>{
 return {id: element.id, number: i, opacity: element.style.opacity};
});

function changeStyle(i) {
    x[i].style.opacity = y[i].opacity;
}

y[0].opacity = "0.6";
y[1].opacity = "0.3";

var i = 0;

for (i; i < y.length; i++) {
    let temp = y[i].number; // same as i
    //initialise style with some predefined opacity
    changeStyle(temp);
    var slider= generateSlider(y[temp].opacity);
    document.body.append(slider);

    slider.addEventListener('input', (obj)=>{
        y[temp].opacity = (obj.target.value/100).toString();
        changeStyle(temp);
    });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main1" class="ctg" style="width:200px; height: 200px; background-color: red;">
            one
        </div>
        <div id="main2" class="ctg" style="width:200px; height: 200px; background-color: blue;">
            two
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Dont know if thats the best that can be, but it works.

Comment: That's what I I'm talkin about, Good job.

Comment: @zer00ne Thank you sir. :)